# @Inject Instance with custom quailfier annotation on class type

Tags: java, cdi

Lets say we have

```
class TestClass1 {  

@Inject @Any @BBB(PARAM1)  
Instance< Product > instaces;

@Produces @BBB(PARAM1)  
Product first(){...}

@Produces @BBB(PARAM1)  
Product second(){...}    
}
```

and

```
class TestClass2 {  

@Inject @Any @BBB(PARAM2)  
Instance< Product > instaces;

@Produces @BBB(PARAM2)  
Product first(){...}

@Produces @BBB(PARAM2)  
Product second(){...}    
}
```

When i put @BBBs on class and remove from methods instances are empty. Is how it works and I have to replicate @BBB on every @Produces methods OR something I have missed?

@BBB is annotated with @Qualifier and RUNTIME retention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but I hope this will clarify it. I think you are mixing several things together.

1) Producers

Those are methods/fields which are *effectively considered beans*! This means that on top of producer you have to define what kind of bean will it create. That boils down to *qualifiers*, *scope*, *stereotypes*,... Whatever you need/want there. This also allows you to have multiple producers which will only differ in, say, qualifier with which they create the bean. **So yes, you need to repeat it on each producer, for it may make a great difference.**

2) Your classes

Your are themselves beans (dependent scope in this case) and you can specify all the CDI stuff on them - scope, qualifiers, etc. This will **not** propagate to the producers inside the beans. If you think about it, that would mean that should your class be application scoped, anything it produces would also be application scoped, **which is not the case.**

Your source of confusion might also be interceptor/decorator (or rather their binding) which can be placed either on bean method (enabling interception for given method) or on top of whole class (enabling interception for *all* methods).